# Tax calculation using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to write a function on pandas which calculates the total yearly tax paid given monthly income on the following basis: the regular rate is *13%*, but when income for the year becomes larger than *1000* units, from the next month tax of *20%* is imposed.
For example, `calculate_tax(pd.Series([150]*12)` should return 286.5. Here 150 is monthly income.

This should be solved without using cycles 
I was able to write a code with the fixed *13%* of the income:

```
def calculate_tax(income):
    t=(income*0.13).cumsum()
    return(t.iloc[-1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
def calculate_tax(income):
    income_cumsum = income.cumsum()
    rate = income_cumsum.apply(lambda x: 0.13 if x<=1000 else 0.2).shift(1).fillna(0.13)
    return (income*rate).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [114]: %paste
def calculate_tax(income, tax1=0.13, tax2=0.2, thresh=1000):
    s = pd.Series([income] * 12)
    return (s.mul(tax1 + s.cumsum().gt(thresh)
                          .shift().fillna(False)
                          .mul(tax2-tax1))
             .cumsum()
             .iloc[-1])

## -- End pasted text --

In [115]: calculate_tax(150, 0.13, 0.2, 1000)
Out[115]: 286.5

In [161]: calculate_tax(150)
Out[161]: 286.5
```

Comment: I need to write function with just one argument, 'income' and with known tax1 and tax2 (0.13,0.2)

Comment: It returns "the truth value of the series is ambiguous"

Comment: @PhilippPhilippov, try to copy & paste the code from my answer

Comment: Did all that, even your code with your function does not work, idk why...